# How do I publish a new website on IIS and make it visible online

Tags: iis

I try to create a simply website on a corporate server with static ip:

I open IIS Manager, right click "Add Website".

I set the binding with static ip and port "7878"

**Note** : This server has already one site that run on port 80

If I open the site directly from server using the static ip (not localhost):

> http://{ip address}:7878/

everything work

If i open from any other computer it gaves me timeout error

Comment: You need to open the port on Windows Firewall.

Comment: You're right! it works thanks! I'm not expert on System Engineer